Is there a scalar product which makes orthonormal the family of complex functions $ (f_n)_{ n \geq 1 } $?
Let $ (f_n)_{ n \geq 1 } $ be a family of complex functions defined as follow,
$ \forall n \geq 1 $,
$$ f_n (z) = \dfrac{1}{n^{z}} $$
I would like to ask you if it is possible to construct a ( non-trivial ) scalar product ( or any bilinear form ) on a certain functional space which makes orthonormal the family $ (f_n)_{ n \geq 1 } $.
If the answer is yes, how to do that ?
Thank you.

You need to specify the function space (and the domain of each function $f_n$). Moreover, bear in mind that if the $f_n$ are linearly independent, as they probably are for any sensible choice of common domain, then there is a linear bijection from the linear span of the $f_n$ onto $c_{00}$, mapping $f_n$ to the basis vector $e_n$; you can then pull back the standard inner product on $c_{00}$ to get an inner product on the linear span of the $f_n$, with respect to which the sequence $(f_n)$ is orthonormal. So I don't think your question is well-posed in its current form.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but perhaps try $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\int_{-x}^xdyf_n(iy)\overline{f_m(iy)}}{2x}$.

For any set of objects $f_n$, you can just declare them to be orthonormal and let them span a Hilbert space ($\cong\ell^2$). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

There is a unique Hilbert function space with that property, and you can read about it here.

You might want to define for the OP what a Hilbert function space (a.k.a. RKHS) is, since it is not clear to me from their question or previous ones that they will be familiar with this term.

@YemonChoi Thanks for your comment. I wanted to keep things simple, but feel free to update my post or add your own, more detailed answer.
